# Gradle build from command line fails with an exception, "Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper"

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I was asked to install `JDK` and `Gradle`, and installed them successfully, `gradle -v` works (version 6.1.1), but if I try to build something, or even type `gradle -tasks` in the command line, it fails:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> *What went wrong:
> Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

I've searched the problem and people who experience it are using React Native or VS or Android Emulator, so solutions are written in those, but I'm only trying to use the command line.

What commands can solve the problem?

(NOTE: I'm quite new to developing)

Answer (score 1):

It is related to your JDK version.

Check https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12599

It happens to me a while ago and I downgraded the jdk version.

I suggest to upgrade Gradle at least to 6.3 or download your jdk.